# Removing Gray lines that show up in layout editor

Tags: qgis, layouts, layout-manager

I have been trying to find a way to remove the gray lines appearing when I try to transfer a map from the QGIS project screen into the layout editor.
These lines do not appear in the aerial imagery, and only appear in the layout editor. They are not a grid that I have put on, and the lines vary with the size of the image.

Attached is an example of these grey lines showing up.

It's becoming a problem as it is showing up in the maps I make for work and therefore impacting the quality of maps clients are receiving.

Comment: Where is  the "Attached"?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the dpi of the map export from 300 either down to 150 or up to 500 for the error to disappear.

Comment: I don't see an attachment

Answer (score 0):

Looks it works to set the Symbology's "Layer Rendering" "Blending Mode" to Darken.
... however, doing this appears to break the layer toggling if you're using the Create Geospatial PDF (all the layers are still visible, but the ability to toggle them on/off in the PDF is no longer available)